# Microsoft Clustering Algorithm - large number of input columns

Tags: sql, algorithm, reporting-services, cluster-analysis

Could you tell me, or show me some link for article how the addition of extra input columns can increase the time it takes to train the model.

I have prepared model for my client and I can't get the result for 26 input columns.

The result I get for 17 input columns after more then 5 hours.

When I try with 26 input columns in log file I find information

> Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException: , An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database.

Can you tell me how each additional input column increases the execution time, memory, etc ...